# In what show did a man travel back in time whenever he heard ‘Do It Again’ by The Kinks?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am trying to remember the name of a TV show from the 90s.

The story is fiction - a man travels back in time every time he hears The Kinks’ song ‘Do It Again’, which may have also been the theme song.

But for the life of me, I cannot remember the title.

I believe this was a short-lived series

Answer (score 8):

The show you're referring to is "[That Was Then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Was_Then)", from 2002.

[image]

Per the blurb on Wikipedia:

> The series starred James Bulliard as Travis Glass, a 30-year-old who
>   finds his life in a rut. Still living at home with his mother (Bess
>   Armstrong) he works as a door-to-door salesman. The girl of his
>   dreams, played by Kiele Sanchez, is married to his older brother,
>   Gregg, played by Brad Raider. Travis is able to trace his life's
>   downward spiral to a single week in high school in 1988. After telling
>   his best friend, played by Tyler Labine, that he wished for a second
>   chance to make everything right, he lies in bed listening to the song
>   "Do It Again" by The Kinks, when a bolt of lightning hits his house,
>   and an electrical jolt sends him back to that week in 1988. Glass
>   tries to correct things that originally went wrong, but finds his new
>   life isn't quite to his expectations, and must return from the past.

That Was Then was cancelled after only two episodes.

Comment: That show sounds awful. How did it even get one episode?

Comment: This show was awesome... sadly too awesome for television =\

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza - It looks ***terrible***.

Comment: Sounds like a Groundhog Day kind of thing where every week he would go back, try to change things, then come back to the present to see them changed and not the way he wanted. Could work if done right.

Comment: @Broklynite - 'Butterfly Effect' meets 'Sliders'